# Content of NavigationView not showing up SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am attempting to create a NavigationView in SwiftUI with a single NavigationLink inside. My code so far is:

```
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: PlayersView()) {
                Text("Players")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(12)

            }
            .background(Color.black)
            .cornerRadius(12)


            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Home"))
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeView()
    }
}
```

Nothing gets displayed in the live preview or when I run on a simulator. The live preview looks like this:

[image: SwiftUI live preview example 1]

If I change the code a little bit and duplicate the NavigationLink then I can get one of the NavigationLinks to appear.

```
struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: PlayersView()) {
                Text("Players")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(12)

            }
            .background(Color.black)
            .cornerRadius(12)

            NavigationLink(destination: PlayersView()) {
                Text("Players")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(12)

            }
            .background(Color.black)
            .cornerRadius(12)

            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Home"))
        }
    }
}
```

[image: SwiftUI live preview example 2]

I am trying to make a home page with multiple links to other SwiftUI screen view files. Any help is appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: It is about iPad orientation, please see my answer for updated details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of this

```
NavigationLink(destination: PlayersView()) {
    Text("Players")
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .padding(12)

}
.background(Color.black)
.cornerRadius(12)
```

do this

```
NavigationLink(destination: PlayersView()) {
    Text("Players")
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .padding(12)
        .background(Color.black)
        .cornerRadius(12)
}
```

**Update**: I assume I've got your issue, which I at first just passed automatically. NavigationView is platform specific. By default iPad has Master/Details navigation style, which has different presentation depending on orientation, so you don't see in Preview your link, because Preview is in Portrait and navigation link is in Sidebar, which is hidden.

If you want to see it in such Preview, you need to use `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())` for `NavigationView`. Or, in your variant, just run application in Simulator and using `CMD-Left/Right arrow` rotate Simulator.

*Note*: It's not possible to rotate Preview or now. Just in case.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that did not make a difference.

Comment: Adding `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())` to the navigation view fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using iPad, I want to say the first `navigationLink` is working  as a sketch/index view which you can get it out by swiping to right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I am also having issues initially but trying this way works for me !!

```
  var body: some View 
  {
      NavigationView 
     {
           VStack(alignment: .center)
              {
                  //Your ui designs
              } 
       .navigationBarTitle(Text("Forgot 
        Password").font(.largeTitle).fontWeight(.medium), displayMode: .inline)

      }
  }
```